# Multidimensional JSON-object through SQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

My database looks like this:

[image]

I have to come up with a SQL-query which will do the following:

1. Make an object for every different value in the column "MONTH"
2. This data should be stored in an array (see the JSON-setup below)

However, I'm stuck at the beginning. Maybe I should do something with SELECT DISTINCT ... ?

My goal is the create the JSON-object as shown below.

```
var data = [
    "val1":[
        {"DATE":a1, "HEADER":b1, "MESSAGES":c1},
        {"DATE":a2, "HEADER":b2, "MESSAGES":c2},
        {"DATE":a6, "HEADER":b6, "MESSAGES":c6},
     ],
     "val2":[
        {"DATE":a5, "HEADER":b5, "MESSAGES":c5},
        {"DATE":a8, "HEADER":b8, "MESSAGES":c8},
     ],
     "val3":[
        {"DATE":a3, "HEADER":b3, "MESSAGES":c3},
        {"DATE":a4, "HEADER":b4, "MESSAGES":c4},
        {"DATE":a7, "HEADER":b7, "MESSAGES":c7},
     ],
];
```

So far I have tried this (but it's only connecting to the database):

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Data";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[] =  $row; 
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Can you show us your php script, and what is exactly your question ?

Comment: @nazanin is correct. Post what  you have already tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP to generate the result in the format you want instead of trying to make a complicated query.

Try this.

*note you need to replace `$row['DATE']` and etc. with the correct column names.

```
<?php

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "user1");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM Data";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $data[$row['MONTH']][] = array(
    "DATE"=> $row['DATE'],
    "HEADER"=> $row['HEADER'],
    "MESSAGES" => $row['MESSAGES']
    ); 
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: One last adjustment, to meet the OP's requirement: each "month" containing an array of objects...

Comment: @TonyChiboucas pretty sure mine does that.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas 'object', in this context means JSON object. My code generates the correct JSON output without `stdclass`.

Comment: `json_decode` will turn it into: `["val1"][ ["DATE": date, "HEADER": header, "MESSAGES": messages] ]`. OP asked for `["val1"] [{"DATE": date, "HEADER": header, "MESSAGES": messages} ]`. Not a big deal, and just semantics. Your solution is perfect, I'm just being a stickler.  ^_^

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit new to this so I don't know what the correct names are. I hope it is clear.

Comment: @JohnPhelps the correct names are the column names in your database table. The same ones in your SELECT statement.

Comment: @JohnPhelps, no worries, you named everything correctly. Use this solution, and mark it as accepted. It's the right way to go.